# Introducing myself to discrete Morse theory

Tags: reference-request, topological-data-analysis

I plan to write my maths masters' dissertation on discrete Morse theory. I intend to write it from a theoretical point of view, relating it to classical Morse theory. I still have to decide exactly what to do, but I would like to learn the basics about discrete Morse theory first.

Which books or articles would you recommend to introduce myself to the topic? I wonder if "A user's guide to discrete Morse theory" by R. Forman or "Discrete Morse Theory" by N. Scoville are good starting points.

Thanks!

Comment: I learned the basics from the applied setting here https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.03844. May be useful. It can get very theoretical but the idea is simple, so maybe don't read a whole book to start off as that can take many months.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [***A User's Guide to Discrete Morse Theory***](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/forman1.pdf) by [Robin Forman](https://math.rice.edu/%7Eforman/), who is a top expert. Its 44 pages so not too long for a master's thesis. Also don't forget the usefulness of recorded seminars and youtube videos, as this subject is quite new in its applications.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any particular seminars/videos in mind that you would recommend?

Comment: Vidit Nanda here for example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QD4-qm2-vTA